# Number above ULONG_MAX during unsigned arithmetic

Tags: c, precision

So I'm working on creating a precise Decimal structure that stores it's characteristic and mantissa within a long and an unsigned long respectfully. Because I'm doing this I've had to come up with my own subtraction and addition functions.

While testing my functions I ran across the troublesome problem of "negative zero". Essentially, I cannot represent -0.1 through -0.9 because there is no way for me to put a negative sign on my zero without just using a flag value of some kind. This is background information and I'll post the code so you can see how I'm doing the arithmetic. The STRANGE behavior though is that I'm getting a number *above* ULONG_MAX. Specifically this is the output of my log:

```
diff->right: 18446744073699551616
b->right10000000
MANTISSA_LIMIT: 100000000
ULONG_MAX: 18446744073709551615
Subtracting 10.10000000 from 10.00000000
Test: tests/bin/decimal.out(subtractDecimalsWithCarry+0x79) [0x40109f]  Decimal: 0.10000000
```

And the code:

helpers/decimal.h:

```
#ifndef __DECIMAL_H__   
#include <limits.h> 
#define MANTISSA_LIMIT 100000000
#define __DECIMAL_H__
typedef struct{          /* Calling them more convenient terms: */
    long left;           /* characteristic */
    unsigned long right; /* mantissa */
}Decimal;

void createDecimal(long left, unsigned long right, Decimal * dec);

/* Perform arithmetic operations on Decimal structures */
void add_decimals(Decimal* a, Decimal* b, Decimal* sum); 
void subtract_decimals(Decimal* a, Decimal* b, Decimal* diff); 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
void createDecimalFromString(Decimal * dec, const char * str);
#endif
```

And then decimal.c's relavant code:

```
/* Subtract two decimals, a - b */
void subtract_decimals(Decimal* a, Decimal* b, Decimal* diff){
    diff->left = a->left - b->left;
    diff->right = a->right - b->right;
    fprintf(stderr, "diff->right: %lu\n", diff->right);
    fprintf(stderr, "b->right%lu\n", b->right);
    fprintf(stderr, "MANTISSA_LIMIT: %d\n", MANTISSA_LIMIT);
    fprintf(stderr, "ULONG_MAX: %lu\n", ULONG_MAX);
    if(diff->right > MANTISSA_LIMIT) { 
    if(diff->right != 18446744073699551616UL)
        diff->left -= 1;            
    else
        diff->left *= -1; /* This is where I might put a flag for -0*/
    diff->right = ULONG_MAX - diff->right + (18446744073699551616UL == diff->right ? 1 : 0);     /* +1 because of the wrap around, we have to 'count' 0. */
    }
}

void createDecimalFromString(Decimal * dec, const char * str){
    long left;
    unsigned long right;
    char * dotLocation;
    char rawLeft[9];
    char rawRight[9];
    int i;
    int dotPos;
    long leadingZeros;
    int numDetected;

    if(str == NULL)
         return;

    bzero(rawLeft,9);
    bzero(rawRight,9);

    dotLocation = strstr(str, ".");
    leadingZeros = numDetected = 0;
        if(dotLocation == NULL){
           left = atol(str);
           right = 0;
        }else{
        /* ghetto strncpy */
        for(i=0; i != 9 && str[i] != *dotLocation; ++i)
            rawLeft[i] = str[i];
        rawLeft[i] = '\0';
        dotPos = i+1;
        left = atol(rawLeft);
        for(i=0; i != 9 && str[dotPos] != '\0'; ++i,++dotPos){
            if(str[dotPos] == '0' && numDetected == 0)
               leadingZeros++;
            else
               numDetected = 1;

            rawRight[i] = str[dotPos];
        }
        rawRight[i] = '\0';
        right = strtoul(rawRight,NULL,10);
        if(leadingZeros > 0)
            /* subtract the leading zeros, then also the powers of ten taken by the number  itself*/
            right = (right*(powlu(10,7-leadingZeros-(i-2))));
        else
            right = right*(powlu(10,(i > 1 ? 8-(i-1) : 7 ))); 
    }

    dec->left = left;
    dec->right = right;

}
```

And finally the calling code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "helpers/decimal.h"

void traceAndPrintDecimal(Decimal testDec){
    int nptrs;
void *buffer[100];
    char **strings; 
    nptrs = backtrace(buffer, 100);
    strings = backtrace_symbols(buffer, nptrs);
    printf("Test: %s  Decimal: %ld.%08lu\n", strings[1], testDec.left, testDec.right);

    free(strings);
}

void subtractDecimalsWithCarry(){
    Decimal oper1;
    Decimal oper2;
    Decimal result;
    createDecimalFromString(&oper1, "10.0");
    createDecimalFromString(&oper2, "10.1");
    subtract_decimals(&oper1, &oper2, &result);
    printf("Subtracting %ld.%08lu from %ld.%08lu\n",oper2.left,oper2.right,oper1.left,oper1.right);
    traceAndPrintDecimal(result);
}


int main(){

subtractDecimalsWithCarry();
return 0;
}
```

And the piece of my makefile for compiling:

```
decimal.o: src/helpers/decimal.c
    cc -I./headers -std=gnu99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g -c src/helpers/decimal.c -o obj/decimal.o

test-decimal: tests/decimal-test.c decimal.o
    cc -I./headers -std=gnu99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g tests/decimal-test.c obj/decimal.o -o tests/bin/decimal.out -lm -rdynamic
```

It's strange that `diff->right` is larger than ULONG_MAX, does anyone know why this might be?  If you need anymore information let me know and I'll do my best to update the question.

Comment: Look a little closer. diff->right is smaller.
18446744073^6^99551616
18446744073^7^09551615

Comment: Oh! you're completely right. I was just looking at the ones place and didn't notice the rest of the number. Phew. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any idea why the ones place goes a little cockeyed? The number should only be off by 1000000 because of the way the mantissa works. But it's off by 10000001 instead. @UncleO

Comment: Please detail the meaning and use of the magic number 18446744073699551616UL in code.

Comment: @chux the magic number is the one I observed in my log that seems out of place. I intend on taking it out, but it was a way to check if was in the range of -0.1 to -0.9 because I was specifically working with those numbers (I don't think it would work with things like .11 since that would modify more places) 
The ones place being off is really the reason for trying to use that number in the first place. If I could figure out why my ones place is off, I wouldn't need any magic number

Comment: `for(i=0; i != 9 && str[i] != *dotLocation; ++i) ...`  Loop could end with `i` with value 9, then `rawLeft[9] = '\0'` writes out of bounds.  Also, rather than use `9`, create a constant or #define.

Comment: Thanks. I was programming this all rather late last night and didn't notice that. I'm only allowing 8 digits of precision so I figured it'd be safe to use i there.

Comment: So you maybe you want `for(i=0; i != (9-1) ...` in a couple places.

Comment: @chux Do you think that that possible extra bit is what's causing the problem with the ones place during the underflow? It doesn't seem like it would, and to me it seems like when my ul underflows it loses a ones place because of going by 0. (0-1)UL so maybe I could just add that one back in, but it seems quirky that 0-100 = ULONG_MAX-99 although it makes sense.

Comment: @EJEHardenberg  I do not think the "extra bit" is your posted problem, but it _is_ a separate problem that should be fixed.  I also do not think you have a loss of one that you need to correct.  0-100 should be (ULONG_MAX + 1) - 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mistaken "Number above ULONG_MAX".

At first glance `diff->right` with the value "18446744073699551616" appeared to be larger than ULONG_MAX ("18446744073709551615").  But is 9999999 less.  (@UncleO)

---

OP's asserts in comment "any idea why the ones place goes a little cockeyed? The number should only be off by 1000000 because of the way the mantissa works. But it's off by 10000001 instead".  Suggest this is incorrect.

```
// from createDecimalFromString(&oper1, "10.0");
oper1.right = 0
// from createDecimalFromString(&oper2, "10.1");
oper1.right = 10000000
// from subtract_decimals(&oper1, &oper2, &result)
diff->right = oper1.right - oper2.right --> 18446744073699551616
```

`unsigned` subtraction is well defined in C.  In this case the difference `oper1.right - oper2.right` will mathematically result in `oper1.right - oper1.right + (ULONG_MAX + 1)`.

" ... a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting type."  C11 6.2.5 8

Comment: Thanks for the unsigned subtraction part with the ULONG_MAX +1 part, I think that will help me again later when I work on this (can only post on this thread for now).I sprintf mantissa values to %08lu in order to store them into a mySQL database Decimal(11,8). Because of the formatter I get my extra leading zeroes that I need, and then I represent .1 as 10000000, .01 as 1000000 etc. I'm doing this because I only care about 8 digits of precision. If "10.0" => 0 mantissa I need to fix that. @chux when I work on this later and get it fixed up using that ULONG_MAX +1 I'll accept this as the answer

Comment: @EJEHardenberg  Should you want portability and since you have 8 decimal digit mantissa, consider using type `uint32_t`.  Your `long` of 64 bits on your machine is 32 on mine.

Comment: Awesome. using: diff->right = (ULONG_MAX+1) - diff->right; gets me the right value for the mantissa, and I'm just going to handle the edge case of the characteristic being a 0 with a flag of some kind. Thanks @chux. I'll look into using uint32_t as the type instead of the long. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/88031-uint32_t-uint32.html#post629524 although, how is uint32_t portalable if it's optional for C99 compilers? (judging from this post)

Comment: @EJEHardenberg raises a good point about portability.  Should you want to use Visual Studio, one does not even have large C99 compliance.  So do we use C89 as the standard?  My suggestion best applies to up-to-date compilers.  As C11 has been out a few years, I target that.  I find more money to be made with new adapters than those at the back end of the tech curve.  Your experience may be different.